# Pass Onload Event Through Redirect

Tags: php

I am wondering if it is possible to call a script through a redirect. I have a contact form using PHP mail that echos a redirect back to the home page, like so;

```
...
header("Location: ../index.php");
...
```

Is it possible to add an onload event that gets passed to the redirected page? So when "index.php" is loaded from the redirect it calls a pop up thank you or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sending them to the next page like this, you could either append some instructions to the end of the url, or you could store them in a session variable and check that upon the next page load - or even a combination of both.

```
session_start();

$_SESSION["redirect_url"] = "options.html";

header("Location: ../index.php?redirected=1");
```

And perform some type of check on the new landing page:

```
session_start();

if ( $_GET["redirected"] && $_SESSION["redirect_url"] ) {
  echo "<script>
          window.onload = function(){
            var myWin = window.open( '" . $_SESSION["redirect_url"] . "' );
          };
        </script>";
}
```