# No "onload" event, on redirect back Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect

First, I found this answer, but they do not suit..

- [Pass onload event through redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643295/pass-onload-event-through-redirect)

My problem is, that I want my AngularJS part of my application to reload something, when the user is redirected back to the page.
The login flow is like this

a.php -> [FB Magic] -> callback.php -> a.php

My problem is `<body onload="foo()">` fires only once. The same is true for `DOMContentLoaded` and `window.onload` as well.

For a.php it is like the user never left the page.

How can I make AngularJS call a function (which is defined within a controller), when the user is redirected back? (I am using PHP for redicting back

EDIT: How my controller looks like ->

```
pwm.controller('EventListController', ['$scope', 'pwmApi',
function EventListController($scope, pwmApi) {
    $scope.fetched = false;
    $scope.events = [];
    let update = function () {
       <!-- Does stuff, is a bit long ->
    };
    update();
}]);
```

So :) The update(); method is called on Construction of the controller. When I am redirected back the update-function is NOT called - Refreshing the page helps.

I sincerly hope this clarification helped. Reloading the page after getting redirected back helps, but now nothing happens...

Comment: when you are redirecting back send a parameter with url ex. rediredt='true' and excess it in controller.

Comment: @AmitSirohiya : Could you explain it please?

Comment: are you using stateProvide or routeProvider to redirect?

Comment: @AmitSirohiya I do not use any of those, the redirect happens in PHP `header("Location: $url");`

Comment: @AmitSirohiya: My problem is on the JS side (how to detect an parameter change in JS/AngularJS) [ `a.php?reload=true` ]

Comment: try to add in your redirect url a timestamp or a randomw generated value  to force your browser to reload the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it in PHP (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8577805/1870799)

Instead of `header("Location: $url");` (was my original redirect solution) and `header("Location: $url?redirect=true");` I am now using
`header("refresh: 0;url=$url");` and it works as expected.

But still... Is it possible with AngularJS to do the same with the Location header?

Answer (score 0):

You can make $url like this -
 `$url = "abc?rediect='true';`

here `redirect='true'` means you are redirecting.

In your angularJs controller do this-

**Controller**

```
.controller('controller',function($location){
   var queryParameters = $location.search();

   // Check if redirect is true
   if(queryParameters.redirect === 'true')}{
      // Call a function
      myFunaction();
   }
});
```

**Update** - in query string all values will be sting so boolean **true** will also become **'true'** so you have to handle that like a string not boolean.

Comment: queryParameters = {}

Comment: What url is generating check in browser?

Comment: Improved my code inject  $location service in controller function.

Comment: `ui/?reload=true` (Of course I changed `queryParameters.redirect`to `queryParameters.reload`
I did inject location. '$scope', '$location', 'pwmApi'``

Comment: The main problem is: Although I call Update in the controller it won't execute. So I do not see how your code should be executed..?

Comment: why a "/ " after ui? Your url should be ui?reload=true;

Answer (score -2):

Listening onload doesn't fit well with angular.

If you're using routing with ngRoute or ui-router or even ng-controller, the associated controller will get executed again. If it's not enough, you can listen to the events provided by the routing modules : $routeChangeSuccess/$stateChangeSuccess

Comment: He already said that he is not using $routeProvider or $stateProvider see comment on his question. He is redirecting through PHP.

Comment: then it 's not an angular problem, if the onload doesn't fire after redirecting